# how to get key and value pair from json like below:-

Tags: arrays, json, typescript

I am trying to get key and value from the below json but do not know how can i get it dynamically. for Angular 5 project.

Component:- here is the method which i want to use in my component.

```
 public AnalyticsRes(_AnalyticsResponse) {

      let ButtonAttribute = _AnalyticsResponse.ButtonAttribute.split(',');
      let Button2Attribute = _AnalyticsResponse.Button2Attribute.split(',');


      let key1 = ButtonAttribute['know-more1'];
      let key2 = ButtonAttribute['know-more2'];

      }


    I am not sure if syntax is correct kind of newbie in angular 

    and here is the HTML CODE:-


<div class="grid-i" *ngIf="response.Button1.trim() || response.Button2.trim()">
                    <a class="xyz" *ngIf="response.Button1.trim()" (click)="ManagaeNavigation(response.ButtonLink);defaultClick();"
                    href="{{response.ButtonLink}}" [analytics-promo]='response.BtnAnalytic ? response.BtnAnalytic : null'> 
                        <span class="buttonClass">{{response.ButtonText}}</span> 
                        <span class="arrowIcon"></span> 
                    </a>
                    <a class="xyz" *ngIf="response.Button2.trim()" href="{{response.Button2Link}}" 
                    [attr.data-analytics-promo]='response.Btn2Analytic ? response.Btn2Analytic : null'> 
                        <span class="buttonClass">{{response.Button2}}</span> 
                        <span class="arrowIcon"></span> 
                    </a>
                </div>
```

here is my json :-

```
    {
        "Items": [
            {
                "Title": "Get it:",
                "field_background_color": "is-bg-color-blue",
                "ButtonLink": "/myUrl",
                "ButtonText": "Visit Site",
                "ButtonAnalytic": "link-analytics:first, link-analytics:second",
                "ButtonTwoLink": "http://dummy.com",
                "ButtonTwoText": "Know More",
                "Button2Analytic": "know-more:first, know-more:second",
                **"ButtonAttribute": "link-analytics:first, link-analytics:second",
                "Button2Attribute": "know-more:first, know-more:second",**
                "ButtonLinkAbsolute": "/abc",
                "ButtonTwoLinkAbsolute": "http://dummy.com",
                "Students": [
                    {
                        "title": "No",
                        "description": "Visit a <a href=\"https://www.google.com"> Outlet</a> dummy ",

                    },
                    {
                        "title": "No",
                        "description": "FREE <a href=\"https://www.google.com"> free </a> dummy.",

                    },
                    {
                        "title": "No",
                        "description": "Bring home",

                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "Status": "OK",
        "StatusMessage": "SUCCESS"
    }
```

Please help me to get key and value from :-

**"ButtonAttribute": "link-analytics:first, link-analytics:second",
                    "Button2Attribute": "know-more:first, know-more:second",**

as there are comma separated values from json and i have to get these into array in my component method, and want to use them in my html ?? here another challenge is that how can i bind multiple attribute to single lement in angular 6?? code plunkar will be more helpful. Thank You in advance.

Comment: what's your expected output? And your input

Comment: @molamk Hi , I have updated my question, please check. I want to iterate over my json array and bind those value s to my html , but one problem is there is already href is bnd to anchor tag in my html how can i bind one more which is coming from json with name:- ButtonAttribute (for 1st anchor) and Button2Attribute(for 2nd anchor).